# How can I avoid double checking in a brute force search?

Tags: python, numpy

I saw a [post](http://www.openculture.com/2015/04/shortest-known-paper-in-a-serious-math-journal.html) on reddit about a counterexample to Euler's conjecture.  I decided to try the brute force calculation myself.

My code is

```
import numpy as np

fifths1  = np.arange(1,151)

fifths = fifths1**5

for x in fifths1:
    for y in fifths1:
        for z in fifths1:
            for w in fifths1:

                lambdas=[x,y,z,w]

                if sum(np.array(lambdas)**5) in fifths:


                    print((x,y,z,w))
```

However, the code takes very long because it triple checks cases.

From the paper I linked, the counter example is

```
27^5 + 84^5 + 110^5 + 113^5 = 144^5
```

My code returns

```
(27, 84, 110, 133)
(27, 84, 133, 110)
(27, 110, 84, 133)
(27, 110, 133, 84)
(27, 133, 84, 110)
(27, 133, 110, 84)
```

How can I optimize the brute force search so that it does not check the same case multiple times.

Comment: If you keep at which index you are in the array in an outer loop, you can slice `fifths` array for the inner loop with a starting index from the outer loop. And then for all layers of outer-inner loop.

Comment: Perhaps you can make the shorter and nicer with [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

Comment: If you know there is only one answer, you could stop the search when you find it.  The other alternatives mentioned so far are good if you want to verify that there is only one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think NumPy is the wrong library to use here.

This isn't a problem that can be easily vectorised in its current form (the biggest reason to use that library) and, furthermore, looping over NumPy arrays is very much slower than looping over Python lists.

You also incur a performance penalty by constructing a new NumPy array each time in the inner loop and using `in` to check the sum (which is `O(n)` in complexity).

As others have noted, `itertools` allows you to test each combination of four fifth-powers exactly once. Checking if the sum of these powers is also a fifth-power using set-membership (`O(1)` complexity) will also boost performance:

```
import itertools

fifths = [x**5 for x in range(1, 151)]
f_set = set(fifths)

[x for x in itertools.combinations(fifths, 4) if sum(x) in f_set]
```

Which quickly returns:

```
[(14348907, 4182119424, 16105100000, 41615795893)]
```

and then you can recover the fifth-roots `(27, 84, 110, 133)` from there.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `itertools.combinations` instead of manually looping:

```
import itertools 
for x, y, z, w in itertools.combinations(fifths, 4):
    #etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid doing the operation multiple times by figuring out the current position in each loop and only starting at that position in later loops:

```
import numpy as np

fifths1  = np.arange(1,151)

fifths = fifths1**5

for i, x in enumerate(fifths1):
    for j, y in enumerate(fifths1[i:]):
        for k, z in enumerate(fifths1[i+j:]):
            for w in fifths1[i+j+k:]:

                lambdas=[x,y,z,w]

                if sum(np.array(lambdas)**5) in fifths:


                    print((x,y,z,w))
```

You can further speed things up by using your pre-computed `**5` values:

```
import numpy as np

fifths1  = np.arange(1,151)

fifths = fifths1**5

fifthsall = np.vstack([fifths1, fifths]).T

for i, (x1, x) in enumerate(fifthsall):
    for j, (y1, y) in enumerate(fifthsall[i:, :]):
        for k, (z1, z) in enumerate(fifthsall[i+j:, :]):
            for w1, w in fifthsall[i+j+k:, :]):
                if x+y+z+w in fifths:
                    print((x1,y1,z1,w1))
```